# I want to select all documents from the collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to select all documents from the collection.
The collection has 8 documents.
I can't choose the eighth document last.

This is the eighth document:

```
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "3d",
"cena": 30.37,
"pohyb": 6.2,
"casZaznamu": "02.04. 13:14"
},
"\__v": 0
```

Contents of the collection:

```
\[{
"\_id": {
"$oid": "6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e8f"
},
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "10m",
"cena": 32.33,
"pohyb": -0.3,
"casZaznamu": "03.04. 18:05"
},
"\__v": 0
},{
"\_id": {
"$oid": "6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e90"
},
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "20m",
"cena": 32.5,
"pohyb": -0.8,
"casZaznamu": "03.04. 17:55"
},
"\__v": 0
},{
"\_id": {
"$oid": "6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e91"
},
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "1h",
"cena": 32.71,
"pohyb": -1.4,
"casZaznamu": "03.04. 17:14"
},
"\__v": 0
},{
"\_id": {
"$oid": "6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e92"
},
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "2h",
"cena": 32.46,
"pohyb": -0.7,
"casZaznamu": "03.04. 16:40"
},
"\__v": 0
},{
"\_id": {
"$oid": "6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e93"
},
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "4h",
"cena": 32.46,
"pohyb": -0.7,
"casZaznamu": "03.04. 16:40"
},
"\__v": 0
},{
"\_id": {
"$oid": "6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e94"
},
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "12h",
"cena": 32.52,
"pohyb": -0.8,
"casZaznamu": "03.04. 10:47"
},
"\__v": 0
},{
"\_id": {
"$oid": "6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e95"
},
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "1d",
"cena": 30.12,
"pohyb": 7.1,
"casZaznamu": "02.04. 18:14"
},
"\__v": 0
},{
"\_id": {
"$oid": "6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e96"
},
"perioda": {
"symbol": "ATOM",
"perioda": "3d",
"cena": 30.37,
"pohyb": 6.2,
"casZaznamu": "02.04. 13:14"
},
"\__v": 0
}\]
```

Query:

```
_dotazChart = await Chart.find({})
console.log(\_dotazChart)

{
perioda: {
symbol: 'ATOM',
perioda: '10m',
cena: 32.33,
pohyb: -0.3,
casZaznamu: '03.04. 18:05'
},
\_id: 6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e8f,
\__v: 0
},{
perioda: {
symbol: 'ATOM',
perioda: '20m',
cena: 32.5,
pohyb: -0.8,
casZaznamu: '03.04. 17:55'
},
\_id: 6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e90,
\__v: 0
},{
perioda: {
symbol: 'ATOM',
perioda: '1h',
cena: 32.71,
pohyb: -1.4,
casZaznamu: '03.04. 17:14'
},
\_id: 6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e91,
\__v: 0
},{
perioda: {
symbol: 'ATOM',
perioda: '2h',
cena: 32.46,
pohyb: -0.7,
casZaznamu: '03.04. 16:40'
},
\_id: 6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e92,
\__v: 0
},{
perioda: {
symbol: 'ATOM',
perioda: '4h',
cena: 32.46,
pohyb: -0.7,
casZaznamu: '03.04. 16:40'
},
\_id: 6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e93,
\__v: 0
},{
perioda: {
symbol: 'ATOM',
perioda: '12h',
cena: 32.52,
pohyb: -0.8,
casZaznamu: '03.04. 10:47'
},
\_id: 6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e94,
\__v: 0
},{
perioda: {
symbol: 'ATOM',
perioda: '1d',
cena: 30.12,
pohyb: 7.1,
casZaznamu: '02.04. 18:14'
},
\_id: 6249c8ad5eab3d3320c33e95,
\__v: 0
}
```

............  The eighth document does not appear here.

```
SCHEMA:
const schemaChart = new mongoose.Schema({
    // vlastnosti objektu 
    perioda: {
        symbol : String,
        perioda : String, 
        cena : Number, 
        pohyb : Number,
        casZaznamu : String
    }
})
```

It works when I insert a line again:  _dotazChart = await Chart.find({}) into block try {} and again some code insert finally code.

```
  try {
    for(i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
      _dotazMove = await Move.findOne({minceID: _idMince, perioda: _perioda[i]}).sort({_id: -1})  
      // new
      let _dokumentChart = new Chart({      
        perioda: {
          symbol: _dotazCoin.symbol,
          perioda: _perioda[i],
          cena: _dotazMove.cenaPred,
          pohyb: _dotazMove.pohyb,
          casZaznamu : _dotazMove.cenaPredCasZaznamu
        }      
      })
      _dokumentChart.save((error, savedDocument) => {
      if (error) console.log(error)
      //console.log("(chart.js): "+savedDocument)
      })
    }
  
    _dotazChart = await Chart.find({})
  } catch {
    res.send("Chyba!")
  }


   _dotazChart = await Chart.find({})
```

Comment: Could you paste the code for your schemas here? It is possible the problem may originate in your schemas.

Comment: instead of using async/await for your query, try using .find with a callback like: `Chart.find({}, function(err, chart) { console.log(chart) })`

Comment: I must have two identical lines in the code: 

 `_dotazChart = await Chart.find({})`